# How are fancy graphical user interfaces coded?

Tags: user-interface, gui-design

I'm wondering about "fancy GUIes" are made.

When I say that, I have in mind softwares like iTunes, Picasa, Skype, Songbird, Spotify, Vlc (themed) ... everything that breaks with standard GUI

in which languages? what frameworks/tools are used?

Comment: This is a poorly phrase question. Also "fancy" is useless as a tag. What you are asking seems to be what toolkits are used to create GUIs for x,y,z. Try searching for gui toolkits in the stack and you'll find the info you want.

Comment: thanks, I'm not an english native speaker. Any comment is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Nothing beats a great design... Must likely all those applications are coded with very different frameworks. I mean, They all look different... good but different.

I don't think this fanciness has anything to do with the framework used but with the creative people behind the UI's design.

If you aim to develop great UIs forget about the framework and look for Design Tips. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758), [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534042) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379376) books should help you with that. Please note that some of these books aim for Web Developing... but they can teach you very basics of UI designs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what platform and language you are developing on.  WPF is a relatively new trend to build GUIs with the .NET framework and there are many others.  [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is an example but not the only one.

Once you decided the tools you'll be using, it's all a question of creativity as all GUI frameworks allow styling of controls in their own way.  Most of the time you'll build your GUI then apply some sort of style sheet to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Does GUi frameworks like qt, wxwidgets or gtk allows full customization of windows? (ie. spotify-like window)

Comment: Yes, although it might be harder or easier to achieve that sort of customization depending on the tool you use.